# Is there a fundamental difference between malloc and HeapAlloc (aside from the portability)?

Tags: winapi, malloc, heap-memory, msvcrt, heapalloc

I'm having code that, for various reasons, I'm trying to port from the C runtime to one that uses the Windows Heap API. I've encountered a problem: If I redirect the `malloc`/`calloc`/`realloc`/`free` calls to `HeapAlloc`/`HeapReAlloc`/`HeapFree` (with `GetProcessHeap` for the handle), the memory seems to be allocated correctly (no bad pointer returned, and no exceptions thrown), but the library I'm porting says "failed to allocate memory" for some reason.

I've tried this both with the Microsoft CRT (which uses the Heap API underneath) and with another company's run-time library (which uses the Global Memory API underneath); the malloc for both of those works well with the library, but for some reason, using the Heap API directly doesn't work.

I've checked that the allocations aren't too big (>= 0x7FFF8 bytes), and they're not.

The only problem I can think of is memory alignment; is that the case? Or other than that, is there a fundamental difference between the Heap API and the CRT memory API that I'm not aware of?

If so, what is it? And if not, then why does the *static* Microsoft CRT (included with Visual Studio) take some extra steps in `malloc`/`calloc` before calling `HeapAlloc`? I'm suspecting there's a difference but I can't think of what it might be.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I found out the hard way...

The difference isn't fundamental, but `HeapReAlloc` (which uses `RtlReAllocateHeap`) does *not* automatically treat a null pointer as a hint to call `HeapAlloc`; it fails instead.

Comment: HeapAlloc also won't allocate memory for 0 sized pointers, where malloc would. Also, HeapAlloc couldn't call malloc, cause that you lead to circular calls if the new handler couldn't rectify the problem

Answer (score 0):

Another important difference:

```
void *ptr = NULL;
HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, ptr);
```

has [undefined behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/heapapi/nf-heapapi-heapfree#parameters), while

```
void *ptr = NULL;
free(ptr);
```

is well defined ([no operation performed](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free)).

**UPDATE 2021:**

The `HeapFree` documentation [has been updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/sdk-api/pull/610) in January 2021, and now states:

> `[in] lpMem`
>
> A pointer to the memory block to be freed. This pointer is returned by
> the HeapAlloc or HeapReAlloc function. This pointer can be **NULL**.

Honestly, it is not clear whether this applies since a specific SDK release or since ever. For sure that parameter was marked with `_Frees_ptr_opt_` already on 10.0.16299.0, so probably was just a documentation issue.